# Computer black screens after a while, no internet connection, no display, but still running?

Tags: windows, crash, minecraft, black-screen-of-death

I run a minecraft server on my spare PC, and it's recently been doing this thing where, after a while, it would kick everyone out of the game, shows up as offline in teamviewer, plugging a monitor into it just shows a black (but still lit) screen. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

CPU: AMD A6-5400k
RAM 16GB DDR3

I don't know anything else unfortunately, it's an old computer.

Comment: does the numlock light on the keyboard toggle while its in this state?

Comment: Not sure, as I don't have a keyboard plugged into it. I normally just turn it on and TeamViewer in. Why?

Comment: well, a kernel-lock would prevent the numlock light from changing state. I have one box that every month or so, just goes into a state where there is no video output or network reachabiity, but it is still on. Thats how I tell whether its time to hold the powerbutton to reboot it. its likely a driver/mobo issue, but I've never bothered to deeply diagnose it.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it then? New motherboard? Driver reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to:

1. Update graphics drivers to latest version. If they are the latest, try reinstalling the same, because drivers can go corrupt due to any reason.
2. As the machine is old, Turn off machine, clean it, remove RAM, HDD and other peripherals; clean them and re-plug them; just to be sure they are well connected.
3. Keep external monitor connected for sometime until you face the issue so that you can see if any error message pops up. We can fix it based on the error.
4. Check error logs in the event viewer to get more information on what is happening.
5. Check if there are any recent updates installed, if yes, try uninstalling them and observe.
6. You can try using safe mode too, if you don't find issue in safe mode, then try reinstalling recent software.

Thanks